# Rav 4 brakes clicking

Tags: toyota

I have a 2005 Rav4 3door. The rear brakes click when driving but the clicking stops when brakes are applied.

Complete Brake kit replaced with new pins,shims, & spring tensioners

Answer (score 0):

There could be a tab, on one of the caliper shims, that's sticking out and making occasional contact with the rotor.